# What is the best way to handle a JSON API response which returns 200 regardless of error or not

Tags: php, json, http, error-handling, guzzle

So I am making a Guzzle HTTP request to some unreliable source (I have no control of).

The response returns one of the 2:

A 200 status code with the following error:

```
{
    "error": "Data source error, please try again"
}
```

and  200 status code with the following response data:

```
{
    "products": {
        "income": "Income Protection",
        "car": "Car Insurance"
    }
}
```

This is how I made the request through Guzzle:

```
        try {

            $client = new Client(array(
                'curl'   => array( CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false ),
                'verify' => false
            ));
            $res = $client->request($method, self::URI . $url, [
                $params
            ]);

            return $res->getBody();
        } catch (ClientException $e) {
            echo Psr7\str($e->getRequest());
            echo Psr7\str($e->getResponse());
        }
```

So when I receive the error response above it won't ever reach the `catch` part of the code as it returns a successful 200 status code.

What is the best way to handle this so I can return an error response appropriately?

Comment: Can't you just check if the response has an `error` value in the root of the data and do the same thing as though it threw some other form of error.

Comment: Check for `error` in the response body or maybe intercept in with the [complete event](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/5.3/events.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$result  = json_decode($res);`

`if(!isset($result->error))...`